# How can I implement a function to return true if array or arrayList refers to a previous element?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

A playlist is considered a repeating playlist if any of the songs contain a reference to a previous song in the playlist. Otherwise, the playlist will end with the last song which points to null.

I need to Implement a function isRepeatingPlaylist that, returns true if a playlist is repeating or false if it is not.

For example, the following code prints "true" as both songs point to each other.

```
Song first = new Song("Hello");
Song second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");    
first.setNextSong(second);
second.setNextSong(first);    
System.out.println(first.isRepeatingPlaylist());
```

Again, this is not a homework exercise, I am doing coding challenges because when I read theory about programming concepts, I can almost understand, but when faced with writing a program I don't know where to start, or how to apply.

```
public class Song {

    private String name;
    private Song nextSong;

    public Song(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNextSong(Song nextSong) {
        this.nextSong = nextSong;
    }

    public boolean isRepeatingPlaylist() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Waiting to be implemented.");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(one);
        list.add(two);
        list.add(three);
        list.add(four);

        if list.contains()
        return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Song first = new Song("Hello");
        Song second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");
        Song third = new Song("a test");
        Song fourth = new Song("survivor");

        first.setNextSong(second);
        second.setNextSong(first);

        System.out.println(first.isRepeatingPlaylist();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean "the same", or "equal"? You should start with writing code that compiles. try something like: String t = getTestSong(); return list.contains(t);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
public boolean isRepeatingPlaylist() 
{
    Set<Song> songs = new HashSet<Song>();
    songs.add(this);
    Song current = this.getNextSong();
    //if you did not implment a getter for the nextSong property I think you should
    while (current.getNextSong() != null && !songs.contains(current.getNextsong())) {

        songs.add(current);
        current = current.getNextSong();
    }

    return songs.contains(current.getNextsong()); 
}
```

Edit 1: As mentioned in the comments of this answer, the `==` in some cases might not be the best because it compares the **memory location** of each object. In order to fix this issue, implementing the methods `hashCode()` and `equals()` are recommended, if you don't know what they are, try reading [this](https://www.journaldev.com/21095/java-equals-hashcode).

Comment: most likely, ==, though technically correct, will result in unwanted situations

Comment: Yup, but as I could see in his code, each `Song` has a reference to the next song, so I think it should be fine. But implementing the `equals` method would be the best for this kind of situation

Comment: that doesn't mean two Songs can't have a reference to the same 'next' song.

Comment: Yes, but in this case he kind of created a linked list where one node has a reference to the next one, so when two songs have a reference to the same song the first song that appears in the linked list will be considered as the loop point and the other one is just a unused object, Idk how he will treat this, but he definitely should

Comment: Will this not be an endless loop in following case: 1->2->3->4->2. So the loop will continue to process 2-3-4-2-3-4-2-3-4-...which are all different from 1

Comment: @Conffusion you're right... I'll try to refactor this and repost

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What would I include in the line?  I would need to pass a parameter in there to map to the function, I assume?       
          System.out.println(first.isRepeatingPlaylist());

Comment: @RShome, yes, I actually thought the function would be in the main class, but as it is in a object, you wont need a parameter to do that, I will edit the answer yet again

Comment: Thanks Henrique, this is awesome. It works expect for one small test condition whereby If playlist repeats, last song should followed by first song, but I'll try and work that bit out myself. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 4):

Please check the answer below:

```
    public boolean isRepeatingPlaylist() {
                Song slow = this.nextSong;
                Song fast = slow == null ? null : slow.nextSong;
                while (fast != null) {
                    if (slow == this || slow == fast)
                        return true;
                    slow = slow.nextSong;
                    fast = fast.nextSong;
                    if (fast != null)
                        fast = fast.nextSong;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: can you explain the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the playlist and add every song to a set on condition it is not yet in the set. Once you reach the end of the list your list is not a repeating list. If you find a song which exists already in the set, you have a repeating list.

```
public boolean isRepeatingList(Song firstSong)
{
    Set<Song> uniqueSongs=new HashSet<>();
    uniqueSongs.add(firstSong);
    Song current=firstSong;
    while(current.getNextSong()!=null)
    {
        if(uniqueSongs.contains(current.getNextSong()))
            return true;
        // add the song to the set, and assign current to the next song
        uniqueSongs.add(current=current.getNextSong());
    }
    // we reached the end of the list without finding any doubles, so:
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be consider the classic problem: linked list has a circle or not.You can find method from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-linked-list-is-circular-linked-list/) to solve but for your it's not easy to construct linked list，we use another method to solve this problem：count the nextSong,code like this:

```
public static boolean isRepeatingPlaylist(List<Song> songs) {
    int counts = 0;
    for (Song song : songs) {
        if (null !=song.getNextSong()){
            counts ++;
        }
    }
    return songs.size() - counts != 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The issue with most answers ( esp. one by Conffusion ) is that its not talking about `hasCode()` & `equals(...)` method for `Song` class even though approach is correct. `uniqueSongs.contains` will not give correct result if these two methods are not properly implemented.

OP has also not shown structure of `Song` class.

2. Second thing in code samples of OP is that which class should have which responsibility is not clear & if I already have a custom linkedlist then Java `ArrayList` won't be needed - though I have added both versions. Use of words - **array** & **arrayList** in question title is confusing because OP has a traditional LinkedList & that has noting to do with Java while **arrayList** is a Java specific DS.

   public class Song {

   ```
   private String data;
   private Song nextSong;

   public Song(String data) {
       this.data=data;
   }

   public String getData() {
       return data;
   }

   public void setData(String data) {
       this.data = data;
   }

   public Song getNextSong() {
       return nextSong;
   }

   public void setNextSong(Song nextSong) {
       this.nextSong = nextSong;
   }


   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       final int prime = 31;
       int result = 1;
       result = prime * result + ((data == null) ? 0 : data.hashCode());
       return result;
   }


   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
           return true;
       if (obj == null)
           return false;
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
           return false;
       Song other = (Song) obj;
       if (data == null) {
           if (other.data != null)
               return false;
       } else if (!data.equals(other.data)) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }

Ideally , there should be a `PlayList` class to create playlist and method `isRepeatingPlaylist` should belong there. I have added in main driver class for simplicity ,

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class RepetablePlaylist {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Begin - construct Song list 
            Song first = new Song("Hello");
            Song second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");
            Song third = new Song("a test");
            Song fourth = new Song("survivor");

            first.setNextSong(second);
            second.setNextSong(first);

            List<Song> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(first);
            list.add(second);
            list.add(third);
            list.add(fourth);
            // End - construct Song list 

            boolean isRepeatable = isRepeatingPlaylist(list);
            System.out.println(" isRepeatable : "+isRepeatable);

isRepeatable = isRepeatingPlaylist(first);
        System.out.println(" isRepeatable : "+isRepeatable);
        }

         private static boolean isRepeatingPlaylist(List<Song> playList) {
             Set<Song> previous = new HashSet<>();
             for(Song song : playList) {
                 if(song.getNextSong() != null && previous.contains(song.getNextSong())) {
                     return true;
                 }
                 previous.add(song);
             }
             return false;
         }

private static boolean isRepeatingPlaylist(Song head) {
         Set<Song> previous = new HashSet<>();
         Song currentNode = head;
         while(currentNode.getNextSong() != null ) {
             if(previous.contains(currentNode.getNextSong())) {
                 return true;
             }
             previous.add(currentNode);
             currentNode=currentNode.getNextSong();
         }
         return false;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sabir for the explanation, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, it will work but the site tells that it is not correct.
Is it ok to add another int member to the class?

```
public class Song {
private String name;
private Song nextSong;
private int rep = 0 ;

public Song(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setNextSong(Song nextSong) {
    this.nextSong = nextSong;
}

public boolean isRepeatingPlaylist() {
    if (this.nextSong == null){
        return false;
    } else {
        rep++;
        if (rep > 1){
            return true;
        }
        return this.nextSong.isRepeatingPlaylist();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Song first = new Song("Hello");
    Song second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");



    first.setNextSong(second );
    second.setNextSong(first );

    System.out.println(first.isRepeatingPlaylist());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


public bool IsRepeatingPlaylist()
{
    HashSet<Song> songs = new HashSet<Song>();
    Song current = this;
    while (current.NextSong != null && !songs.Contains(current.NextSong))
    {
        songs.Add(current);
        current = current.NextSong;
    }
    return songs.Contains(current.NextSong);
}
```

Comment: How is this different from other answers posted?

Comment: I think this is C# exam task, and this is code, that pass it. It is very similar to Henrique Sabino, but I think my exam not accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is my c++ code, it runs greatly!

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class Song
{
public:
    Song(std::string name): name(name), nextSong(NULL) {}

    void next(Song* song)
    {
        this->nextSong = song;
    }

    bool isRepeatingPlaylist()

    {

        set<string> playlist;
        Song *temp=this;
        while(temp->nextSong!=NULL){
            if (!playlist.insert(temp->name).second) return true;
             temp=temp->nextSong;
        }
        return false;

    }

private:
    const std::string name;
    Song* nextSong;
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    Song* first = new Song("Hello");
    Song* second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");

    first->next(second);
    second->next(first);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << first->isRepeatingPlaylist();
}
#endif  */
```